# Elasticsearch how to sort with condition

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nested

On my ElasticSearch (2.x) I have documents like this:

```
{
    "title": "A good title",
    "formats": [{
        "name": "pdf",
        "prices": [{
            "price": 11.99,
            "currency": "EUR"
        }, {
            "price": 18.99,
            "currency": "AUD"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I'd like to sort documents by `formats.prices.price` but only where the `formats.prices.currency === 'EUR'`

I tried to do a nested field on `formats.prices` and then run this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "and": [
          {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "formats.prices.price": {
      "order": "desc",
      "nested_path": "formats.prices",
      "nested_filter": {
        "term": {
          "currency": "EUR"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But unfortunately I cannot get the right order.

UPDATE:
Relevant part of mapping:

```
   "formats": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "prices": {
            "type": "nested",
            "include_in_parent": true,
            "properties": {
              "currency": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "price": {
                "type": "double"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will solve your problem

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "formats.prices",
            "filter": {
              "match": {
                "formats.prices.currency": "EUR"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [
    {
      "formats.prices.price": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested_path": "formats.prices",
        "nested_filter": {
          "match": {
            "formats.prices.currency": "EUR"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Nope. It seems it rewrites all the currency to 'EUR' and the order isn't correct.

Comment: can you give me your mapping ?

Comment: "properties": {
"formats": {
"type": "nested",
"properties": {
"name": {
"type": "string"
},
"prices": {
"type": "nested",
"properties": {
"price": {
"type": "double"
},
"currency": {
"type": "string"
}
}
}
}
},
"title": {
"type": "string"
}
}

Comment: something like this ? it's working for this one i have checked

Comment: Mmmm what is changing is `formats` is not nested in my mapping, should I change it to nested too?

Comment: I don't know if the problem could be `formats` also is an array.

Comment: change formats to nested. query wont work if it's not nested.